# Succinct way to change thrown Exception to Failure?

Tags: error-handling, exception, try-catch, raku, rakudo

Is there a more succinct way to lift a thrown Exception to a Failure than the following?

```
try {
    die 'always';
    CATCH { default { fail $_ } }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a more succinct version of moritz' code.

```
(try something()) orelse fail $!;
```

Comment: `(try something) // fail` also triggers if `something` returns an undefined value (and doesn't even throw an exception).

Comment: @moritz AFAIK the same is true for orelse.

Answer (score 6):

```
try something();
fail $! if $!;
```

Note that `CATCH` blocks apply to all statements in the same scope, even to code after the `CATCH` block. So if you want to use CATCH blocks, be careful about keeping the scope small.

Answer (score 5):

The try block is superfluous

```
die 'always';
CATCH { default { fail $_; } }
```

but I wouldn't worry about saving typed characters.  Your intent is clear and highly readable.

Saving typed characters at the cost of expressing your intent or readability might have a place in Perl's legacy, but it's not the place you want to find yourself doing maintenance programming.

Comment: `fail` also exists as a method on `Exception`, so you could also: `CATCH { default { .fail } }`

Comment: Other than there being more succinct idioms like `(try die 'always') // fail`, wouldn't it be better to write `CATCH { .fail }` instead of `CATCH { default { .fail } }`? I think it expresses intent clearly and highly readably. It appears to work as I intend on a recent Rakudo. Adding in the `default` seems to make the dying message worse and my explorations haven't revealed a way it makes something better. Aiui using a `when` or `default` statement in a `CATCH` block marks an incoming exception as handled but isn't that moot if the block then `fail`s out?

Comment: For simple code a `try` is superfluous if you have a `CATCH` block and, conversely, a `CATCH` block is superfluous if you have a `try`.