# Exit the function without aborting the script

Tags: raku, rakudo

I have a function that accepts an array of positive values only. Dies when any negative value is given.

```
# Consider edge cases
# First check if all elements are > 0, if not throw informative error
# Then if any of element is zero return 0
# Only else proceed further towards calculation


sub geometric_mean(@data) {
    if @data.any < 0 {die "Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values"};
    if @data.any == 0 { return 0 };
    my $sum;
    for @data {
        $sum += log($_);
    }
    return exp($sum/@data.elems)    
}
```

With this if I try to run the **script**:

```
my @data = [1, 2, 3.8, -1];
say geometric_mean(@data);

say "Hello world";
```

the code exits at the function call without running the last line i.e does not run the codes down the function:

```
Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values
  in method throw at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/Exception.rakumod line 65
  in sub die at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/control.rakumod line 255
  in sub geometric_mean at c:\Users\suman\sum.p6 line 8
  in block <unit> at c:\Users\suman\sum.p6 line 20
```

The modification:

```
sub geometric_mean(@data) {
    if @data.any < 0 {die "Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values"};
    CATCH { default { warn "    Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values"; } };
    if @data.any == 0 { return 0 };
    my $sum;
    for @data {
        $sum += log($_);
    }
    return exp($sum/@data.elems)    
}
```

now runs the last line too with output:

```
    Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values
Nil
  in sub warn at 'SETTING::'src/core.c/control.rakumod line 269
Hello world
```

How to handle such cases?
I looked at `try` `CATCH` blocks but that would execute the code below those blocks *within the function* which I want to avoid.

I went through this:

1. [Succinct way to change thrown Exception to Failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49890095/succinct-way-to-change-thrown-exception-to-failure)
2. https://docs.raku.org/routine/throw
3. https://docs.raku.org/type/Exception
4. https://dev.to/lizmat/exceptions-3g0i

Comment: Usually the catch is where you call the function, not in it.

Comment: Why not change the `die` to a `fail`?  `fail "Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values" if @data.any < 0`

Answer (score 6):

`die` is for *fatal* exceptions. If you want to continue control flow, you don't want a fatal exception.

There are two ways you could fix this. First, use `fail` instead of `die`, and then check if the call failed with a `with`:

```
sub geometric_mean(@data) {
    if @data.any < 0 {fail  "Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values"};
// etc
}

my @data = [1, 2, 3.8, -1];
with geometric_mean(@data) -> {} else {say .exception.message};

say "Hello world";
```

The other way is to not throw an exception at all, and instead *return*:

```
sub geometric_mean(@data) {
    if @data.any < 0 {say  "Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values"; return};
// etc
}

my @data = [1, 2, 3.8, -1];
geometric_mean(@data);

say "Hello world";
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking "how can I avoid the backtrace details emitted on a fail or die??

If so, you can just not generate an exception, like this:

```
sub geometric_mean(@data) {
    if @data.any < 0 { return "Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values" }
    if @data.any == 0 { return 0 };
    my $sum;
    for @data {
        $sum += log($_);
    }   
    exp($sum/@data.elems)               
}

my @data = [1, 2, 3.8, -1];
say geometric_mean(@data);

say "Hello world";
```

```
Not possible to calculate geometric mean for negative values
Hello world
```

EDIT: removed my speculative speculative try/CATCH variant since per comment not good to use try and CATCH in the same block.

Comment: Note you shouldn't use `try` if you intend on using `CATCH`.

Comment: @RawleyFowler `try` is useful to keep the scope of the `CATCH` contained to what it needs to be. If they got rid of the `try` then the `CATCH` would prevent e.g. typoed method names from throwing an error

Comment: although it also occurs to me that just creating a new scope with `{ }` is probably a better idea since it would not affect a typoed method name inside of the `CATCH`

Comment: @RawleyFowler "Note you shouldn't use `try` if you intend on using `CATCH`." While `try` and `CATCH` are typically not used together (because `try` *always* catches *everything*), I see scenarios in which I think it would make sense to combine them (even though I don't recall doing so). So presumably your point was that .@librasteve's code used a `CATCH` *with a `default` case*, so it *also* handled *everything*, making it redundant. Right?